# Induction Proof Help

Tags: induction

Q: By induction on n prove that for all positive integers $n^2\ge1$

A: When n=1, $$n^2\ge1=1^2\ge1$$$$1\ge1$$

Suppose n=k, $$n^2\ge1=k^2\ge1$$

** This is as far as I can get unto without getting stuck, I know that I have to assume that n=k+1 for the last part, but it is what I do after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use that $\forall n>0, (n+1)^2>n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n^2\geqslant1$, then$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\geqslant1+2n+1\geqslant1..$$